# ¿Por qué se muestra una pantalla blanca mientras se sube y procesa un archivo CSV en PHP?

Tags: php, csv, mariadb

Actualmente estoy trabajando en PHP con un proyecto web con arquitectura MVC; la tarea principal que se ejerce es la de subir archivos en formato CSV a una base de datos en MariaDB. El proyecto funciona sin problemas, pero hay un detalle en el que al momento de que se está subiendo el archivo, se muestra la pantalla en blanco mientras se está subiendo a la base de datos; una vez que se sube por completo el archivo, la pantalla en blanco desaparece y se vuelve a mostrar la interfaz con el respectivo mensaje de éxito que le añadí. ¿A qué se debe esto? No manejo archivo demasiado grandes, ya que con un archivo relativamente pequeño (8 KB) me sucede dicha aparición de la pantalla en blanco.

No tenía problema con dicho detalle en un principio, pero ahora quiero mostrar una imagen .GIF con un aro giratorio para que el usuario sepa que se está llevando a cabo el proceso de subida del archivo, pero al mostrarse la pantalla en blanco, no encuentro forma de mostrar dicha imagen. ¿Cómo podría dejar de mostrarse la pantalla en blanco mientras se sube un archivo?

Adjunto mi código:

**VISTA (HTML)**:

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="file" required/>
   </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="importar_archivo" value="IMPORTAR"/>
 </fieldset>

  <?php
     $excel = new ControladorEventos();
     $excel ->ctrImportarExcel();
  ?>

</form>
```

**CONTROLADOR:**

```
static public function ctrImportarExcel()
{
    if(isset($_POST["importar_archivo"])) 
    { 
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 
        $file_open = fopen($file,"r"); 

        while(($datos = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $no_empleado = $datos[0];
            $fecha = $datos[1]; 

            $tabla = "events";

            $respuesta  = ModeloEventos::mdlImportarExcel($tabla, $datos);
        }

        if($respuesta=="ok")
        {
            echo"<script>
                Swal.fire({ 
                    title: '¡Éxito!',
                    text: 'Importe exitoso',
                    icon: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText:'Entendido'
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = 'checadas';
                        }
                    });
            </script>";
                
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<script>
                    Swal.fire({ 
                        title: '¡Error!',
                        text: 'Algo salió mal',
                        icon: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText:'Entendido'
                        });
                 </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

**MODELO:**

```
<?php
    require_once "conexion.php";
    class ModeloEventos{

    //Importación de archivo CSV con checadas a la base de datos

    static public function mdlImportarExcel($tabla,$datos)
    {
        $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(no_empleado,start_event) VALUES(:no_empleado,:start_event)");
            
        $stmt->bindparam(":no_empleado",$datos[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(":start_event",$datos[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return "ok";
        }else{
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt ->close();
        $stmt = null;
    } 
?>
```

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Probablemente estás manejando archivos grandes y la pantalla blanca se muestra mientras los estás procesando. Creo que la mejor opción sería usar AJAX.

Comment: @Triby, me sucede con un archivo de 8 KB. ¿Realmente tendrá que ver el tamaño del archivo en ese caso?

Comment: ¿Cuánto dura la pantalla blanca? Si es mucho tiempo, entonces también influyen las características del servidor, cantidad de usuarios conectados, etc. De cualquier forma, si quieres evitarla, insisto en que realices el proceso por AJAX.

Comment: @Triby, sólo es mientras se están realizando las inserciones en la base de datos. Una vez termina el proceso, se quita la pantalla blanca y se despliega el mensaje de éxito. Revisaré la opción de usar AJAX, pero quería ver una solución más breve para evitar retrabajar

Comment: Una "solución más breve" podría requerir que comiences a enviar salida al navegador y después proceses el archivo, pero esa salida estaría incompleta y, además, hay factores externos que podrían hacer que no funcione como esperas, por ejemplo, que PHP, el servidor, el navegador (o los tres) manejen un búfer y retengan la salida hasta haber acumulado determinada cantidad de caracteres.

Comment: Un consejo. Que el tamaño del archivo sea pequeño, pero la pantalla se quede en blanco un tiempo considerado excesivo, mientras se realizan las inserciones en la base de datos, apunta a que seguramente hay margen de mejora en la optimización de esas inserciones. Por ejemplo, es posible que realices una inserción por cada fila. Te interesará más acumular valores de varias filas para realizar una inserción múltiple. Podrías hacer, no sé, una inserción múltiple cada 100 filas, esto te divide entre 100 el número de intrucciones que vas a enviar a la base de datos. Y puede ser más.

Comment: Porque parece claro que no se queda en blanco mientras se sube el archivo, sino mientras se procesa.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que usas `sweetAlert` para mostrar los mensajes en pantalla.

Puedes hacer uso de esta herramienta para mostrar un mensaje mientras se cargan los datos. Te dejo una propuesta y tu la adaptas a tu código.

Esto se agregaría a tu controlador:

```
if(isset($_POST["importar_archivo"])) 
    {
        echo"<script>
            Swal.fire({ 
                title: 'Procesando la información',
                text: 'Por favor espere...',
                icon: 'info',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                allowEscapeKey: false,
                allowEnterKey: false,
                onOpen: () => {
                   swal.showLoading()
                }
            });
        </script>";
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        ...
```

Las funciones pueden variar en función de la versión de `SweetAlert` que estés usando. Prueba con las que te dejo o revisa la documentación de tu versión.